# Assume f and g are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = q $ and $\lim_{x\to q} g(x) = r $.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**(a) Give an example to show that it may not be true that** $\lim_{x\to p} g(f(x)) = r$

If we are to assume that f and g are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, wouldn't that mean that f and g are continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$? In what circumstance would a discontinuity arise so that this would not be true, or can this statement not be true even if there was no discontinuity?

**(b) Show that the result in (a) does occur even if f and g are continuous.**

**(c) Does the result in (a) hold if f is continuous? How about if only g is continuous?**

Comment: Consider the function $f(x):=\text{sgn}(x)$, is it continuous? Is it defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, consider the following:  Let
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}1&x=0\\-1&x\not=0\end{cases}.
$$
Let $q=0$; then $\lim_{x\rightarrow q}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=-1$.  Therefore, $r=-1$.  Let
$$
f(x)=0.
$$
Suppose that $p=0$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0=q$.

Now, $g(f(x))=g(0)=1$.  Therefore, $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}g(f(x))=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}1=1\not=r$.

The question doesn't state that $p$, $q$, and $r$ are universally quantified; as stated, you just need to be able to pick values for $p$, $q$, and $r$.  The reason that this example works is that limits at a point don't depend on the value of the function at the point, but by choosing $f$ to be the constant function, $g(f(x))$ only sees the value of the function $g$ at the point $0$ and not the the value of $g$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thoughts on part c?

Comment: If you follow the ideas, you can get that it's ok if only $g$ is continuous, but not if only $f$ is continuous. @Rhaldryn.